# Hiding table or assigning temp data based on visibility expression ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table in ssrs 2008. This table has a row visibility expression like:

```
=IIF(max(Fields!VExpected.Value) <> "", 1, 0) + 
 IIF(max(Fields!MExpected.Value) <> "", 1, 0) + 
 IIF(max(Fields!PExpected.Value) <> "", 1, 0) = 3, false, true)
```

Sometimes the datasource returns no data, or the returned data is not matching with this expression. In this case what I see is that a table with borders and column names but no data on it like:

```
id Vex Mex Pex
```

However, I want to show it as

```
id Vex Mex Pex
-  -   -   -
```

Or if possible:

```
id Vex Mex Pex
No Data
```

Another question is, is there any way to hide the complete table if there is no returning data or any matching data with the expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountRows function to determine how many rows your dataset is returning. If it is zero hide the table otherwise show it.

```
=iif(CountRows("DataSetName")=0,true,false)
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset.

For not matching expression data you can use the this expression.

```
=IIF(
max(Fields!VExpected.Value) <> "" AND
max(Fields!MExpected.Value) <> "" AND
max(Fields!PExpected.Value) <> "",False,True
)
```

The whole expression for matching expression and no rows cases could be something like this:

```
=Switch(
CountRows("DataSetName")=0,true,
max(Fields!VExpected.Value) = "",true,
max(Fields!MExpected.Value) = "",true,
max(Fields!PExpected.Value) = "",True,
true,False
)
```

Supposing VM, ME and PE expected values are numeric type I'd use `ISNOTHING()` function to determine when null values are being returned.

```
=Switch(
CountRows("DataSetName")=0,true,
ISNOTHING(max(Fields!VExpected.Value)),true,
ISNOTHING(max(Fields!MExpected.Value)),true,
ISNOTHING(max(Fields!PExpected.Value)),True,
true,False
)
```

Additional you can set a message when no rows are being returned from your dataset. Select the tablix and press `F4` to see properties window. Go to NoRowsMessage property and use an expression to say your users there is no data.

```
="There is no data."
```

In this cases the tablix will not appear in your report but the message you set will be rendered in the location where the tablix should be.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: CountRows("DataSetName")=0 is not useful for me since generally there are some returning data from the SP but the expression in row visibility does not show them on the table. For example CountRows("DataSetName") is 321 in one of my case but there is no data seen in the table.

Comment: NoRowsMessage property also does not work for this situation.

Comment: So why did you ask if there is a way to hide the complete table if there is no returning data? You question is unclear.

Comment: My question is: How can I show "There is no data" for a matrix on ssrs where there is no row displaying under the matrix even though there are many rows returned by the stored procedure the matrix related? For this situation NoRowsMessage is not working, because I guess it thinks there are some data returning from the query, however because of row visibility expression there is no data the matrix is showing and NoRowsMessage cannot understand it as I see

Comment: Share sample of the data your dataset is returning and explain when the data should be shown and when the tablix should be hidden.